# Finding volume of a solid by integrating

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified axis. $y=x^4$, $y=1$; about $y=7$.

I've tried doing this problem using the washer method, but I can't seem to get the actual answer.

I'm hoping someone can tell me where I'm going wrong. Here is what I have so far:

\begin{align}
v &= \int_a^b (\pi r_{\text{out}}^2 - \pi r_{\text{in}}^2)  \\
&= \int_0^1 \pi \cdot 7^2 - \pi (7 - x^4)^2 \\
&= \pi \cdot 49x - \frac{\pi}{9} x^9 + \frac{14\pi}{5} x^5 - \pi \cdot 49 x \Big|_0^1 \\
&= -\frac{\pi}{9} + \frac{14\pi}{5}
\end{align}

This answer is wrong, and I've been stuck on this problem for a few hours, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture?

Comment: I've graphed it a few times. Cant seem to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: You let out the second-quadrant part. Could have taken care of it by multiplying by $2$, because of the symmetry. We want $2\int_0^1\pi\left((7-x^4)^2-6^2\right)\,dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second line:

$v = \int_{0}^{1} \pi(7)^2 - \pi(7-x^4)^2$

is wrong in the limits and the integrand. It should be:

$v = \int_{-1}^{1} \pi(7-x^4)^2 - \pi(6)^2$